# Call childs of parent object siblings

Tags: javascript, json, object, javascript-objects

Hi, I'm trying to make my own Pokédex site, but sinds I'm not very good at databases, SQL, PHP and such, I'm doing it in JavaScript, JSON style. While doing this I bumped into a problem: I wanted to refer `gen1.gps.Route_1.Exits.South` to `gen1.gps.Pallet_Town.Title` but I didn't know how. Of course I searched the internet for a while first, to find a solution, but I didn't understand it in the context.

```
var gen1 = {
  'gps': {
    'Route_1': {
      'Title': 'Route 1',
      'Exits': {
        'North': 0,
        'South': // pallet town link here
      },
    },
    'Pallet_Town': {
      'Title': 'Pallet Town',
      'Exits': {
        'North': /* route 1 here */,
        'South': 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I expect to be able to call the `gen1.gps.Route_1.Exits.South` object to get the `Title` object of `gen1.gps.Pallet_Town`.

I haven't debugged anything yet so I have no idea what my errors are or will be.
I hope somebody can help me by posting a useful answer.

Comment: You can't. Once you have created `gen1`, you can set up the references, but you cannot do it "while" creating it.

Comment: and if I would make a function object?

Comment: That depends. You can only set a reference to an existing object. If your function does that, it'll work. If it tries to do the same as your code above, it won't.

Comment: @ChrisG ok, and if I would make the object without referring to other objects, could I set those references after that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to implement some kind of id system. MySQL takes care of this for you, but like you said, you don't want to have to learn new languages just to see something come to life.

I added IDs to the routes, and then wrote a function to find routes by their IDs. The bottom bit of code (`Object.size()`) is to get the total number of routes in your `gps` object. (Same as `array.length`)

```
var gen1 = {
  'gps': {
    'Route_1': {
      'Id': 1,
      'Title': 'Route 1',
      'Exits': {
        'North': 0,
        'South': 2
      },
    },
    'Pallet_Town': {
      'Id': 2,
      'Title': 'Pallet Town',
      'Exits': {
        'North': 1,
        'South': 0
      }
    }
  }
};

function getRoute (id)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < gen1.gps.size(); i++)
    {
        if (gen1.gps[i].id == id)
            return gen1.gps[i];
    }

    return false;
}

Object.size = function (obj) 
{
    var size = 0, key;

    for (key in obj) 
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty (key)) size++;

    return size;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save a lot of work if you create your object dynamically, like this:

```js
var gen1 = {
  gps: {}
};

function checkPlace(a) {
  if (!gen1.gps[a]) gen1.gps[a] = {};
  if (!gen1.gps[a].Title) gen1.gps[a].Title = a.split("_").join(" ");
  if (!gen1.gps[a].Exits) gen1.gps[a].Exits = {};
}

function connect(a, b, dir) {
  checkPlace(a);
  checkPlace(b);
  if (dir == "ns") {
    gen1.gps[a].Exits.South = gen1.gps[b];
    gen1.gps[b].Exits.North = gen1.gps[a];
  }
  if (dir == "we") {
    gen1.gps[a].Exits.East = gen1.gps[b];
    gen1.gps[b].Exits.West = gen1.gps[a];
  }
}

connect("Route_1", "Pallet_Town", "ns");

console.log(gen1.gps.Route_1.Exits.South.Title);
console.log(gen1.gps);
```